# xcode 8 searching for editor extensions

Tags: xcode8, xcode-extension

Xcode8 now officially support editor extensions, and forbids code injection, preventing previous extensions (served by Alcatraz for example) to execute.

It may be a dumb question, but I'm totally unable to find an answer:
**Where can I search for existing Xcode8 extensions?**

For example, with Alcatraz there was a panel in `Window > Extensions`, which presented a list with all available extensions. With Xcode 8.0 (official release) there is no such option.

[In WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/414/), the guy talks abound downloading them from the mac App Store. But again, I'm unable to find a category or any one of them.

(note: I'm still on El Capitain)

Comment: I am searching for "highlight all occurrences of selected word" extension...

Comment: You can search for "Xcode extension" and it returns some, but not all. "Developer Tools" is the overall category, but obviously that also lists a lot of non-extension stuff.

Comment: I guess I should write an Xcode extension that search for Xcode extensions into the App Store :)

Answer (score 2):

This is all I could find:

- [Awesome native Xcode extensions](https://github.com/tib/awesome-xcode-extensions)
- [Xcode-8-extensions](https://theswiftdev.com/2016/08/17/xcode-8-extensions/)

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode extensions can be found on the App Store, for example i have been able to find this one: [Text Toolset](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/text-toolset/id1157225201?l=en&mt=12)

They have to be enabled after installing by going to the system preferences > extensions.

Overall they are really hard to find, as they do not have a separate category on the App Store.